# Sort net group output in one column

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch-file, active-directory

The command `net group "Groupname" /domain > c:\temp\users.txt` will generate the following output in the text file.

```
Group name     GroupABC
Comment        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Members

--------------------------------------------------------------------
MemberA                  MemberB                  MemberC 
MemberD                  MemberE                  MemberF 
MemberG                  MemberH                  MemberI
The command completed successfully.
```

I'd need to get rid of the unnecessary header and comment at the end of the file and simply have the output in an ordered list as follows:

```
MemberA
MemberB
MemberC
MemberD
MemberE
MemberF
...
```

Is there an easy way to do this without having to output to the file and remove the header manually? Your help with the sorting and removal of unnecessary spacing is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this I can think of is to do it in powershell with the Active Directory cmdlets. Either on the domain controller or a machine with RSAT installed, run the following

```
Get-ADGroupMember GroupName | select name | out-file GroupName.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are missing AD cmdlets, you could format the results of `net` in Powershell.

```
# store the results in an array.
$results = net group "Groupname" /domain

# the size of the header and footer is always the same. select the data between these sections.
$results = $results[8..($results.Length-3)]

# replace the empty spaces with a comma. join on the comma, getting rid of blank lines.
foreach($result in $results) { 
    ($result -replace '\s+',',') -split ',' | ? { $_ } >> 'C:\temp\users.txt'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using just a batch file to convert the output to a single column.

Create a batch file named "convert-to-single-column.bat" or something like that and paste in this code.

```
@echo off

if "%~1" == "" (
echo Usage: %0 file.txt
exit /b 1
)

for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3*" %%A in (%1) do (
echo %%A
echo %%B
echo %%C
)
```

Run the command:

```
net user /domain >> users.txt
```

Then run the command:

```
convert-to-single-column.bat users.txt > users-single-column.txt
```

Now you have a single column, no powershell or python necessary.
Note, the top of the text file will still contain...

```
The
request
will
User
accounts
for
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
```

And the bottom will contain...

```
The
command
completed
```

The usernames will all be there in the center though.

Happy hacking!